# Hosting your website on your LAN

Tags: easyphp

There's this little issue i have. my website has been hosted on the intranet before using easyphp but now, i want to host it but with a name like samuel.org such that if i connect to the same network my computer(which is the server) is on and you enter samuel.org, it takes you to my developing site. Thanks in advance. By the way, virtual host has been tried.

Answer (score 0):

Editing your local host file should accomplish this.

On Windows you can go to `%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` and add it like so:

`127.0.0.1          domain.com`

And as for linux, you can go to `/etc/hosts` and edit that file and do the same

Comment: I use windows.. The thing is i'm new to this, can you please elaborate on the hosts stuff. Thanks

Comment: Sure, open the Run prompt and type `%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` in the editbox. Once you get a prompt to choose what to open the hosts file with, choose notepad or any text-editor. Add a new line that says `127.0.0.1 samuel.org`, turn on your webbrowser and go there. What this does is creates a "fake" should I say domain connection. Changes the IP Address of a domain to your local IP Address (i.e. 127.0.0.1) See this for more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)

Comment: I just tried it now..When i entered the website from another computer on the network, it didnt go. What do i do please?

Comment: Okay I misread your question at first, and I went for a walk unrelatedly and remember it. Now, just set a port like 8080, or just 80, get your local IP by your Network Settings, then just go to the IP address from another website!

Comment: Yeah..instead of going to an IP address from the other system connected to the LAN, I want to just enter an address like Samuel.org for instance.

Comment: You'd have to edit the host files like I said, but instead of adding the local IP address of 127.0.0.1, you'd enter your LAN IP Address